# make a Jenkinsfile that uses Generic-Webhook-Trigger and acts like a regular multibranch-pipeiine job with how it handles jobs from branches and PRs

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

with Jenkins multibranch pipeline job, it will create a separate job for each branch and each PR. How can I setup a multibranch pipeline job that uses a Jenkinsfile with the Generic-Webhook-Trigger add-on and have it act in the same way with how it processes each branch and each PR?

A common issue I keep coming across is that all the branches and PRs get processed under the same job because trigger criteria for that job allows for all of them.